# PHP converting plain text to hashtag link

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I am trying to convert user's posts (text) into hashtag clickable links, using PHP.

From what I found, hashtags should only contain alpha-numeric characters.

```
$text = 'Testing#one #two #three.test';
$text = preg_replace('/#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/i', '<a href="/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>', $text);
```

It places links on all (#one #two #three), but I think the `#one` should not be converted, because it is next to another alpha-numeric character, how to adjust the reg-ex to fix that ?

The 3rd one is also OK, it matches just #three, which I think is correct.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking here - you may get a better answer on StackOverflow. Can you clarify what your intended outcome would be?

Comment: I meant to post it at StackOverflow, I must have had multiple tabs open. But I think the question is clear, I don't see a way to improve it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could modify your regex to include a negative lookbehind for a non-whitespace character, like so:

```
(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/mR4jZ7

PHP:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', '<a href="/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>', $text);
```

**Edit:**
And to make the expression compatible with other languages (non-english characters):

```
(?<!\S)#([0-9\p{L}]+)
```

Working example:

https://regex101.com/r/Pquem3/1

Comment: Thanks, maybe you want to also add the full code: `$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/m', '<a href="/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>', $text);`

Comment: You're welcome!  Yes, I edited answer to include PHP code. Thanks. :)

Comment: Can you tell me also how to skip hashtags starting* with numbers ? e.g `#123test`.

Comment: @adrianTNT, yes, you could do this: `(?<!\S)#([^0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: I read some specs that said hashtags can only start with letters, but I see twitter allows it. The code works though.

Comment: Thanks that works and for sharing example to the regex101, awesome tool!

Comment: @MElliott Hello to all , Really thanks for that answer, I found that its not working for chinees or some other words .#печаль #грусть #fıstıklıbaklava #чайная #джаз   Can you let me know why?

Comment: @PrateekSaluja , yes, to make the regex compatible with all languages, `(?<!\S)#([0-9\p{L}]+)` works great!

Comment: @MElliott Do you use drupal? I have installed the [hashtags module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hashtags), but it is not converting to links.

Comment: I wrote a function for hashtags and profile links: https://glot.io/snippets/f3yun76ev1

Comment: unicode do not works, how to resolve this?

Comment: @Monzur, the Unicode modifier flag and compatibility varies depending on the language and regex engine you are using. See here: https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/18161/unicode-modifier

Answer (score 2):

With uni-code, html encoded safe and joined regexp; `~(?<!&)#([\pL\d]+)~u`

Here `some&#39;s tags like #tag1 #tag2#tag3` etc.

Comment: this regex was the only good working with everything including non-English and start of line hashtags, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have found the solution like: facebook or others hashtag to url solutions, it may be help you too. This code also works with unicode. I have used some of Bangla Unicode, let me know other Languages work as well, I think it will work on any language.

```
$str = '#Your Text #Unicode #ফ্রিকেলস বা #তিল মেলানিনের #অতিরিক্ত উৎপাদনের জন‍্য হয় যা #সূর্যালোকে #বাড়ে';
$regex = '/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z\p{L}\p{M}]+)/mu';
$text = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="' . BASE . 'search?q=$1">#$1</a>', $str);
echo $text;
```

Comment: A solution using Unicode characters was posted 6 years ago, not to mention the edit to the accepted answer. Does this improve on those solutions? How? Edit your question to include this information. Doesn't `\p{L}` include a-z?

Answer (score 0):

To catch the second and third hashtags without the first one, you need to specify that the hashtag should start at the beginning of the line, or be preceded one of more characters of whitespace as follows:

```
$text = 'Testing#one #two #three.test';
$text = preg_replace('/(^|\s+)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(\b|$)/', '$1<a href="/hashtag/$2">#$2</a>', $text);
```

The `\b` in the third group defines a word boundary, which allows the pattern to match #three when it is immediately followed by a non-word character.

Edit: MElliott's answer above is more efficient, for the record.